# How can I mark a property as deprecated in delphi?

Tags: delphi, properties, deprecated

I want to mark a property in Delphi as deprecated for removal later. According to the Delphi documentation deprecated may be appended to any declaration, but it's not working for properties. Is there a way to do this?

This is what I tried:

```
property SomeProp: string
  read   FSomeProp
  write  SetSomeProp; deprecated 'Use SomeOtherProp instead';
```

Comment: As an aside, if it was supported, I think the semicolon wouldn't be there (cf all supported cases).

Comment: As another interesting aside: if the field is deprecated (`FValue: Integer deprecated;`), it can be used by a property _without_ generating a warning: E.g. `property Value: Integer read FValue write FValue;` <-- No warning!! (At least in D2007.)

Comment: I know this is old and the answers are all here, but FWIW. If you only ever used the read or the write aspects of this property then you could remove the property and add either a function or procedure named "SomeProp" to replace it. That new func/proc could then be flagged as deprecated.

Comment: As yet another aside, the semicolomn is required when you want to deprecate a class method, but must be omitted when you want to deprecate a record field. I mean, who needs consistency anyway?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

No, this is not possible. According to [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements),

> The 'hint' directives **platform**, **deprecated**, and **library** may be
>   appended to any declaration. These directives will produce warnings at
>   compile time. Hint directives can be applied to type declarations,
>   variable declarations, class, interface, and structure declarations,
>   field declarations within classes or records, procedure, function, and
>   method declarations, and unit declarations.

Comment: Damn, I was afraid that this was the case. I don't suppose there is a good workaround for this?

Comment: @Tellmor: My first idea was that you can mark the setter (if there is one; in this case `SetSomeProp`) as deprecated.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't generate a compiler hint when the property is used.

Comment: There is an Embarcadero QC report for this, in case anyone out there wants to vote for it!
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=96350

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 3):

If your property were read-only, then you could use a simple workaround.

The code would go from this:

```
property SomeProp: string read FSomeProp; deprecated 'Use SomeOtherProp instead';
```

to this:

```
function SomeProp: string; deprecated 'Use SomeOtherProp instead';
```

If it were me, i would go the route of:

```
function SomeProp: string; deprecated 'Use SomeOtherProp instead';
procedure SetSomeProp(Value: string); deprecated 'Call SomeOtherProp := Value instead';
```

This way you get a *deprecated* warning only if someone is mistakenly still using it, [rather than getting a warning from now and forever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50834106/12597)

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that; however, you could write a deprecated code in the property setter/getter!

So, in your case you should've created a SetSomeProp setter like this:

```
Type
    TYourClass = class
    private
      procedure DummyDepricated; deprecated 'Use SomeOtherProp instead';
      procedure SetSomeProp(const AValue: string); 
    published
      property SomeProp: string read   FSomeProp write  SetSomeProp; 
    
    implementation
    
    procedure TYourClass.SetSomeProp(const AValue: string); 
    begin
      DummyDepricated;
      //the old setter code here
    end;
    
    procedure TYourClass.DummyDepricated;
    begin
      //this is dummy
    end;
```

Comment: I don't think this does help. What this does is generate a warning that DummyDepricated is used when compiling the unit TYourClass is implemented in. But this does not warn if any consumer is using the property that is about to be removed outside of that unit.

Comment: actually this will show "Use SomeOtherProp instead"

Comment: Yes, but the warnings will be there because you yourself are using a deprecated procedure. There will be no additional warnings for using the soon to be removed property - which is the point of this question.

Comment: I knoww, this is why i wrote "You can't do that" at the begining, i am not giving an answer for the question, and i couldn't write my solution in a comment because it contains a little big code for a comment, this is why i added it like an answer, my idea was just to give a solution that may help for this question at the first place, and not giving an answer...